# random.choice with a list

Tags: python, random, nlp

I have a list of 30 strings. I want to use the choice method of the random module and generate a new string from the list they are stored in. I don't want to repeat any strings and I want to print all the unique strings once. I am trying to make a chat bot but I can only get 1 string to print over and over every time I run the program

```
print("you are speaking with Donald Trump. If you wish to finish your conversation at any time, type good bye")
greetings = ["hello", "hey", "what's up ?", "how is it going?", ]
#phrase_list = ["hello", "the wisdom you seek is inside you", "questions are more important than answers"]
random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

print(random_greeting)
open_article = open(filePath, encoding= "utf8")

read_article = open_article.read()
toks = read_article.split('"')
random_tok = random.choice(toks)
conversation_length = 0
responses = ''

while True: #getting stuck in infinite loops get out and make interative
    user_response = input(" ")
    if user_response != "" or user_response != "good bye":
        responses = responses + user_response
        conversation_length = conversation_length + 1
    while conversation_length < 31:

        print(random_tok)
    if conversation_length >= 31:
        print("bye bye")
```

Comment: Can you please include your code snippet as well?

Comment: I added the code above. it doesn't show it but I imported random at the beginning of the program just didn't paste it

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `random.choice()`. Use `random.shuffle()` instead to put the (unique) words in random order instead, then repeatedly take from that list. That ensures that a) you use all the words, and b) don't repeat any picks:

```
random_greetings = greetings[:]  # create a copy
random.shuffle(random_greetings)
```

and then whenever you want a random word, just use:

```
random_greeting = greetings.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need "random selection without replacement." This function, called on a list of strings, will return a random string. Called more than once, it won't ever return the same item.

```
import random

def choose_one(poss):
    """
    Remove a randomly chosen item from the given list, 
    and return it.
    """
    if not poss:
        raise ValueError('cannot choose from empty list')
    i = random.randint(0, len(poss) - 1)
    return poss.pop(i)
```

Comment: Why create an entirely new function with `pop()` rather than using `random.sample` or `random.shuffle`?

Comment: Because `random.sample()` implements "selection without replacement" for a single call, but doesn't modify the underlying list, so the "without replacement" condition doesn't hold across multiple calls. `random.shuffle()` randomizes the order of a list, but doesn't select from the list without replacement. Either API could be depend on for the OP's original program, but this function is simple, easily understood, and instructive, and gets to the OP's question, esp. the core problem stated in its first paragraph.